# "won't imagine "vs "don't imagine"

Tags: present-tense

You probably --------------------( not imagine) where I ----------------(write) you from

answer  don't imagine am writing I was just  wondering if "won't imagine "can fit to because she can only imagine once she has received the letter. So for me it is a future time .
[http://olmo.pntic.mec.es/~renciso/ejercicios_1/tiempos%20verbales_gapfilling_1.htm](http://olmo.pntic.mec.es/%7Erenciso/ejercicios_1/tiempos%20verbales_gapfilling_1.htm) EXERCICE 2

In the  exercice 3 I think there is a mistake "she has left school.She **has left** school in july" . I am sure it should be left as july is certainly finished and the period is precised

Comment: One question in one post would be recommended. Also your question is getting difficult to comprehend.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. But allow me to give you a tip: *Elle est partie de l'école en juillet* is not *has left*. **The passé composé in French is simple past in English: She left school in July**. And French speakers often make this mistake in English when they are beginners....[precise is not a verb in English. The verb is specify.] **Typically, in [month, day, hour, year, etc.] take the simple past in English and not the present perfect**.

Comment: OK That is what I think so there is a mistake in the solution given it should be "she left school in July". What is unclear in the first part of my question . I just would like to know if we can say in the sentence written you won't imagine where I am writing instead of don't imagine . I  have given the link to the test

Answer (score 1):

- > You probably won't imagine where I am writing you from.
- > You probably can't imagine where I am writing you from.

Both of these are correct and reasonably idiomatic. "can't imagine" is a bit stronger in meaning than "won't imagine" is. "where I am writing you from." is perfectly correct, but feels slightly awkward or old-fashioned to me. I might write something such as:

- > You probably won't imagine where I am at this time.

or 'at the moment". This drops the explicit idea of the place that the writer is writing from, but "at the moment" obviously means the time of writing, so the essential meaning is unchanged, and the trailing proposition "from" which, while not incorrect, can feel odd is avoided.

---

On the 2nd question:

> She has left school in July.

is incorrect. It would be incorrect even if July was the current month, or a future month.

> She left school in July.

would be the normal way to express this when July is in the past.

- > She is leaving school in July.
- > She will leave school in July.

are both correct and natural for a future action.

In future please stick to one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

Letters are mostly written in present tense. Ellen will get this letter in future but you are writing it in present. (Don't imagine) and (am writing)  are right answers.